# How can i keep my code dry in ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dry

As in the following code: i am sending two ajax requets which are the same the only difference is one line, how can i wrap it up into a function to keep my code DRY?

```
$('.searchable').multiSelect({
    selectableHeader: "<input type='text' class='search-input' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Select reservations ex. \"12\"'>",
    selectionHeader: "<input type='text' class='search-input' autocomplete='off' placeholder='Remove selected reservations \"'>",
    afterInit: function(ms){
        var that = this,
            $selectableSearch = that.$selectableUl.prev(),
            $selectionSearch = that.$selectionUl.prev(),
            selectableSearchString = '#'+that.$container.attr('id')+' .ms-elem-selectable:not(.ms-selected)',
            selectionSearchString = '#'+that.$container.attr('id')+' .ms-elem-selection.ms-selected';

        that.qs1 = $selectableSearch.quicksearch(selectableSearchString)
            .on('keydown', function(e){
                if (e.which === 40){
                    that.$selectableUl.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });

        that.qs2 = $selectionSearch.quicksearch(selectionSearchString)
            .on('keydown', function(e){
                if (e.which == 40){
                    that.$selectionUl.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });
    },
    afterSelect: function(value){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/police/get_res_price?price=' + value,
            success: function (data) {
                var initial_price = parseInt($('.give-me-money').val());
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(obj, function(booking_price, value) {
                    initial_price += parseInt(value.BOOKING_PRICE);
                });
                $('.give-me-money').val(initial_price); //set total
            }
        });
        this.qs1.cache();
        this.qs2.cache();
    },
    afterDeselect: function(value){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/police/get_res_price?price=' + value,
            success: function (data) {
                var initial_price = parseInt($('.give-me-money').val());
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(obj, function (booking_price, value) {
                    initial_price -= parseInt(value.BOOKING_PRICE);
                });
                $('.give-me-money').val(initial_price); //set total
            }
        });
        this.qs1.cache();
        this.qs2.cache();
    }
});
```

Comment: how? just do it. `function foo() { ajax stuff here } ... afterDelesect: foo, afterSelect: foo`

Comment: What the difference between them? I cant tell them apart.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is; it seems like you already know the answer ("wrapping them in a function"). In fact there are two functions you should abstract: the before/after function, and the success functions. Only the success functions differ; you could write a function generator that takes an arg to indicate add/subtract, or have the success functions call a small helper function that does the actual math, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ajaxHandler = function(decrement) {
    return function(value){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/police/get_res_price?price=' + value,
            success: function (data) {
                var initial_price = parseInt($('.give-me-money').val());
                var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(obj, function (booking_price, value) {
                    if (decrement) {
                        initial_price -= parseInt(value.BOOKING_PRICE);
                    } else {
                        initial_price += parseInt(value.BOOKING_PRICE);
                    }
                });
                $('.give-me-money').val(initial_price); //set total
            }
        });
        this.qs1.cache();
        this.qs2.cache();
    }   
}

$('.searchable').multiSelect({
    // other props
    afterSelect: ajaxHandler(false)
    afterDeselect: ajaxhander(true)
});
```

Comment: Please see the edited code now, the full one i cannot break it into functions i need something that i can call inside the afterselect and beforeselect

Answer (score 2):

Wrap them both in a single function which takes an `operationType` argument.  You can use that argument to multiply by -1 when your subtracting.  That way you always add in your code but have the effect of subtracting on the deselect operation.

```
$(".searchable").multiSelect({
    //selectableHeader etc,
    afterSelect: function(value) { selectionChange(value, "select"); },
    afterDeselect: function(value) { selectionChange(value, "deselect"); }
});




function selectionChange(value, operationType) {
    var bookingPrice;
    if(operationType === "deselect") {
        bookingPrice = parseInt(value.BOOKING_PRICE) * -1;
    } else if(operationType === "select") {
        bookingPrice = parseInt(value.BOOKING_PRICE);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/police/get_res_price?price=' + value,
        success: function (data) {
            var initial_price = parseInt($('.give-me-money').val());
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(obj, function (booking_price, value) {
                initial_price += bookingPrice;
            });
            $('.give-me-money').val(initial_price); //set total
        }
    });
    this.qs1.cache();
    this.qs2.cache();
}
```

Comment: I think this is the better answer since they both share the same internal function reference.

Comment: You need to move the `bookingPrice`-section into the `$.each()` for this to work.

Comment: Please see the edited code now, the full one i cannot break it into functions i need something that i can call inside the afterselect and beforeselect

Comment: @IlanHasanov You can still use the function.  Just call it inside your configuration.

Comment: @caeth Good catch, thanks.